# Socket.io.js is not loaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm working with node.js and express.js, and I'm trying to add socket.io to one of my .ejs files but when I'm doing that I get some weird errors:

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)                socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MV6f2K2
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)                                     socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MV6f2cR
```

and then,per second :

```
 GET https://www.mywebsite.eu/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MV6f2cR 404 (Not Found)                   socket.io.js:7
```

There are my files:
app.js:

```
    const fs = require('fs');
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const http = require('http').Server(app);
    const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);
    .....
    var router = express.Router();
    var pathView = __dirname + "/views/";
    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
    app.use(express.json());
    const listenPort = 8000;
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(express.static('public'));
    app.use('/public', express.static('public'));
    app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/'));
    //SOCKET IO PART

    io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    });

   //SOCKET IO PART

   ..........
   app.get & app.post requests
   ..........

   app.use( "/", router);

   // Not found
   app.use("*",function(req,res){
   res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
   res.status(404).send('Page introuvable !');
   });

   // Run server
   app.listen(listenPort, function () {
   console.log('Example app listening on port ' + listenPort )
   })
```

profile.ejs:

```
   .....content of the page(it's working well).......
   <%- include('scripts') -%>
   <script src="/scripts/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

   </html>

   <script>

   var socket = io();

   </script>
```

I have to mention that I copied the socket.io.js from socket.io-client and I put it into socket.io if I wouldn't have done that I would have got a 404 file missing error in devtools.

Hope the rest of the code is not required, I didn't add it because it was a lot and it has nothing to do with socket.io.

Comment: `require('http')`  & `GET https://`  , Are we missing something here, are you running this behind a reverse proxy. ?

Comment: actually I run this on https,yes

Comment: So if you access directly on your reverse proxy server, eg.  `http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js`  what do you get?

Comment: 502 Bad Gateway (nginx)

Comment: What is nginx doing listening on port 8000?.   Port 8000 is the port your running your node.js on, ngnix shouldn't be in the picture.

Comment: wait,my bad,I'm sorry...nginx has nothing to do with this...actually I get 404 when I'm trying to access that page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try and break it down a little bit to identify your problem. You are clearly not reaching your socket.

Try to have a server just like this:

```
var express         = require('express')
var app             = express()
var server          = require('http').Server(app)
var io              = require('socket.io')(server)

io.on('connection', function(socket) {  
    console.log('Socket did connect');
});

server.listen(8080)
```

And Client:

```
var socket = io();
```

If this works, which it very much should, try to add the rest of your code. Ejs shouldn't be the problem since it's compiled to regular HTML before it's served. 
A problem would be if you have you client running on a different domain (or port) than the server. If so, you would have to define it inside the io() on the client site, eg: `var socket = io("http://localhost:8080")`

Comment: Good answer, if the OP runs your code, he could check the first stage with -> `http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js`  If he doesn't get back a javascript file, then there is something really weird going on.  Corrupt, or very old version of nodejs / express / socket.io, maybe..

Comment: Hi again,and thank you for helping me!
I tried and did a server like you mentioned above and it works very well on http(accessing via IP and port) but when I try to access it via https I get the following error:

        index.js:83 WebSocket connection to 'wss://www.mywebsite.eu/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=MumuB9NRPyMh7C4BAAAA' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

Any idea why?

Comment: Hi again,PROBLEM SOVED!All I had to do was to replace from app.listen() ----> http.listen()